# Using the ndisprot example driver (in the WDK) with C++

Tags: c++, driver, using, ndis

I have compiled succesfully the ndisprot example ndis driver that came with the Windows Driver Kit, but I don't know how to use it from C++ to send or receive packets. Could someone instruct me on how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Review the .html file for details.  The prottest sample app that exercise the driver is available in the src\network\ndis\ndisprot\60\test directory.  Shows you how to use the Read/WriteFile and DeviceIoControl functions.

Comment: Ok thanks, I discovered this by myself but since this is the answer I will let other readers know.